# Redirect to a page/URL after alert button is pressed

Tags: javascript, php

i have referred to this two questions [call php page under Javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157029/call-php-page-under-javascript-function) and [Go to URL after OK button in alert is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394131/go-to-url-after-ok-button-in-alert-is-pressed). i want to redirect to my index.php after an alert box is called. my alert box is in my else statement. below is my code:

processor.php

```
    if (!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($office_id) && !empty($title) && !empty($var_title) && !empty($var_story) && !empty($var_task) && !empty($var_power) && !empty($var_solve) && !empty($var_result)) {

    (some imagecreatefromjpeg code here)

    else{
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
        echo 'alert("review your answer")'; 
        echo 'window.location= "index.php"';
        echo '</script>';   
    }
```

it's not displ ying anything(no alert box and not redirecting). when i delet this part `echo 'window.location= "index.php"';` it's showing the alert. but still not redirecting to index.php. hope you can help me with this. please dont mark as duplicate as i have made tose posts as reference. thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're missing semi-colons after your javascript lines. Also, `window.location` should have `.href` or `.replace` etc to redirect - [See this post for more information.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
echo 'alert("review your answer");'; 
echo 'window.location.href = "index.php";';
echo '</script>';
```

For clarity, try leaving PHP tags for this:

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("review your answer");
window.location.href = "index.php";
</script>
<?php
```

NOTE: semi colons on seperate lines are optional, but encouraged - however as in the comments below, PHP won't break lines in the first example here but will in the second, so semi-colons **are** required in the first example.

Comment: semicolons are optional. It's a good idea to use them, but it won't break without them ?

Comment: True, probably just the `location.*` thing then

Comment: @adeneo They are optional if you do a line-break.  If you put it all on the same line, then they are necessary. Echo does not automatically line-break, so the code would all be on one line.

Comment: @TimWithers - Yup, and that's the correct answer, just adding EOL or \n would also work !

Comment: @scrowler thanks for yor answer. i will try them now and let you know what happen. thank you

Comment: @adeneo thanks but how can i place this inside echo? without messing up with quotation marks thanks

Comment: TimWithers and @adeneo thank you guys for you effort and ideas. really appreciate it:)

Comment: Can someone explain why this wouldn't work in a .done() function after an ajax call? it skips over the alert and goes straight to the redirect. thank you

Comment: @egar it would work within an ajax callback. If you have a question you should ask it separately, because it sounds very different to this question.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (window.confirm('Really go to another page?'))
{
    alert('message');
    window.location = '/some/url';
}
else
{
    die();
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering my question. uhm something that worked for me is like scrowler's answer. but your answer is really appreciated too! thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Like that, both of the sentences will be executed even before the page has finished loading.

Here is your error, you are missing a ';'
Change:

```
       echo 'alert("review your answer")'; 
       echo 'window.location= "index.php"';
```

To:

```
       echo 'alert("review your answer");';
       echo 'window.location= "index.php";';
```

Then a suggestion:
You really should trigger that logic after some event. So, for instance:

```
           document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick=function(){
                 alert("review your answer");
                 window.location= "index.php";
           };
```

Another suggestion, use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com)

Answer (score 3):

`window.location = mypage.href` is a direct command for the browser to dump it's contents and start loading up some more. So for better clarification, here's what's happening in your PHP script:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
echo 'alert("review your answer");'; 
echo 'window.location = "index.php";';
echo '</script>';
```

1) prepare to accept a modification or addition to the current Javascript cache.
2) show the alert
3) dump everything in browser memory and get ready for some more (albeit an older method of loading a new URL
(AND NOTICE that there are no "\n" (new line) indicators between the lines and is therefore causing some havoc in the JS decoder.

Let me suggest that you do this another way..

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">\n'; 
echo 'alert("review your answer");\n'; 
echo 'document.location.href = "index.php";\n';
echo '</script>\n';
```

1) prepare to accept a modification or addition to the current Javascript cache.
2) show the alert
3) dump everything in browser memory and get ready for some more (in a better fashion than before) And WOW - it all works because the JS decoder can see that each command is anow a new line.

Best of luck!

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. you and scrowler gave me the same answer. thank you guys for a bunch of help!

Answer (score -1):

Working example in php.
First Alert then Redirect works.... 
Enjoy...

```
echo "<script>";
echo " alert('Import has successfully Done.');      
        window.location.href='".site_url('home')."';
      </script>";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<head>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x;
        var r = confirm("Do you want to clear data?");
        if (r == true) {
            x = "Your Data is Cleared";
            window.location.href = "firstpage.php";
        }
        else {
            x = "You pressed Cancel!";
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Retest</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

This will redirect to new php page.